# Is there a way to append nohup output file?

Tags: nohup

I run my script with this command

```
nohup python a.py > /var/log/a.log 2>&1&
```

This is okay but every time I run this command /var/log/a.log file is truncated. Is there a way to append this file no matter what?

Comment: try `nohup python a.py >> /var/log/a.log 2>&1&`

Comment: Thank you. If you answer the question, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the below command to append the output as well as the standard error to `/var/log/a.log` file.

```
nohup python a.py >> /var/log/a.log 2>&1&
```

`>>`- Append

`>`- Overwrite